# how hasnext() works in collection in java

Tags: java, list, class, collections, package

program:

```
public class SortedSet1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {  

    List ac= new ArrayList();

    c.add(ac);
    ac.add(0,"hai");
    ac.add(1,"hw");
    ac.add(2,"ai"); 
    ac.add(3,"hi"); 
    ac.add("hai");

    Collections.sort(ac);

    Iterator it=ac.iterator();

    k=0;

    while(it.hasNext()) {    
      System.out.println(""+ac.get(k));
      k++;     
    }
  }
}
```

output:
ai
hai
hi
hw
hai

how it execute 5 times??
while come to hai no next element present so condition false. But how it executed.

Comment: The real question is, How do I use an Iterator and why am I getting an indexOutOfBounds-exception.

Answer (score 16):

Your loop above iterates through the list using an index. `it.hasNext()` returns true until `it` reaches the end of the list. Since you don't call `it.next()` within your loop to advance the iterator, `it.hasNext()` keeps returning true, and your loop rolls on. Until, that is, `k` gets to be 5, at which point an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown, which exits the loop.

The proper idiom using an iterator would be

```
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

or using an index

```
for(int k=0; k<ac.size(); k++) {
  System.out.println(ac.get(k));
}
```

However since Java5, the preferred way is using the *foreach loop* (and *generics*):

```
List<String> ac= new ArrayList<String>();
...
for(String elem : ac){
    System.out.println(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the point is ac.get(k) doesn't consume any element of the iterator at the contrary of it.next()

Answer (score 0):

That loop will never terminate. it.hasNext does not advance the iterator. You have to call it.next() to advance it. The loop probably terminates because k becomes 5 at which point the Arraylist with throw a bounds exception.

The correct form of iterating a list (containing strings) is either:

```
Iterator it = ac.iterator();
while (it.hasNext) {
  System.out.println((String) it.next());
}
```

Or if the list is typed, e.g. ArrayList

```
for (String s : ac) {
  System.out.println((String) s);
}
```

Or if you absolutely know this is an array list and need speed over terseness:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ac.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(ac.get(i));
}
```